# Calculating MSE for two different size matrixes

Tags: matrices, matlab, mean-square-error

I have two $2$-column matrixes, one of the has $467$ rows while the other one has $61468$ rows. Both them are trajectory paths of same robot, the big matrix is kind of raw data and the smaller one is filtered data. What's the deal? I have to calculate MSE for these two. How should I make them to have same size? bigger matrix most be smaller by omitting data or I have to add some fake arrays to the smaller matrix to make it bigger?

**Off-topic:** I have bunch of these matrixes that I have to compare one by one, Does **MATLAB** or any other app has built in functions for this?

This is an example of my matrixes: (red one is bigger one)
[image]

Comment: This question is about MSE. This is better for meta.

Comment: @Awesome, meta is for question about math.SE not mean square error. This smells more like an A.I or robotics problem rather than a pure math problem.

Comment: @achillehui Just a light hearted pun.

Comment: I agree with achille hui, not about the pun but about the nature of this question. I think this question is more suited to a robotics/AI forum --- or even [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) --- than to here. By the way, the answers to your question may be very different if your trajectory data also carry time stamps.

Comment: There is no timestamp, the only problem is calculating MSE. I fixed size problem.